# How to make AuthorizeAttribute in parent controller execute before AuthorizeAttribute in derived controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, authorize-attribute

Suppose I have this `FirstExecuteAttribute:AuthorizeAttribute` in the parent controller

```
 [FirstExecute]
 public abstract class ParentController: ApiController
```

And then this `SecondExecuteAttribute:AuthorizeAttribute` in the derived controller

```
 [SecondExecute]
 public class DerivedController: ParentController
```

I thought this hierachy structure would ensure that `FirstExecute` execute before `SecondExecute` but not really. What is the best way to achieve what I want then?
This is a .NET Framework Web API project.